# Not getting any response when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This is my html page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using AJAX</title>
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<body>
    <form action="searchItems.php" name="searchItem" method="post">
        Enter item name : <input type = "text" name = "itemName" id = "itemName" placeholder = "Enter item name" onblur="ajax()" />
        <input type = "submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
        <input type = "reset" name = "reset" id= "submit" value = "Reset" />

        <div id="desc"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is the php page when the form is submitted. The results are as expected.

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    //echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,1)."</pre>";
    $conn   = db_connect();
    $name   = $_POST['itemName'];
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM itemreceived where name = '" . $name . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            echo $row->description;
        }
    } else {
        echo "No result";
    }
}
?>
```

This is the dbconnect.php page used in the searchItems.php page

```
<?php
function db_connect()
{
    $conn       = null;
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $pwd        = "";
    $db_name    = "ebay_db";
    $conn       = mysqli_connect( $servername, $username, $pwd, $db_name );
    if ( !$conn ) {
        die( "Connection failed :" . $conn->connect_error );
    }
    If ( $conn ) {
        //echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Connection successful"); </script>';
    }
    return $conn;
}
?>
```

This is the ajax() function used in the html page to get the result in the div "desc".

```
function ajax(){
var itemName = document.getElementById('itemName').value;
console.log(itemName);
var url="searchItems.php";
envelop = new XMLHttpRequest();
envelop.open("POST",url,true);
envelop.onreadystatechange=displayResult;
envelop.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
envelop.send('itemName='+itemName); 
alert("Calling ajax");
```

}

```
function displayResult(){
    if((envelop.readyState==4) &&( envelop.status==200)){
        document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML=envelop.responseText;
        alert("Part 2");
    }
}
```

When I submit the form, I get the expected result in the page searchItems.php
The ajax() function is not working. The objective is to get the result in div "desc" as soon as the function blur() is activated.

Comment: What mean is not working ? Any errors in console ?

Comment: No, i am not getting any errors, but the result is not displaying in the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove isset($_POST["submit"]) because its just only for submiting form and it returns fals for your ajax function!

Comment: I need to use only Javascript AJAX. Will this continue to work ?

Comment: try this code for define envelop `envelop = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`

Comment: what is exactly not work? can you show the code of invoking your ajax function update your question

Comment: I'll explain you the problem. When I click on the button submit, I get the result of what i'm expecting on that page.

What i want to achieve is that as soon as I enter the word "Cooler" in the textbox and press tab, the description appears in the div "desc". 

I have already posted all the codes I have written in the description. Please find the invoking of the method ajax() in the html page

Comment: so where is the code that you set for your for submit using ajax and invoke ajax() function

Comment: There it is : Enter item name : <input type = "text" name = "itemName" id = "itemName" placeholder = "Enter item name" onblur="ajax()" />

Comment: your form submited before the ajax function invoked! so use this code to prevent submiting form i will update my answer

Comment: @farhadamjady really man?, are you posting other users solutions as yours?

Comment: @phobia82 is this yours? no I dont need to do that if its your solution I will rate for you ;)

Comment: @farhadamjady This answer was effective for me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the `readyState` and `status` in the callback function of the `ajax` call, `envelop` is not available there since it is declared within the scope of the `ajax()` function. Perform the check on `ajax()` and then call for `displayResults()`

```
function ajax(){
    var itemName = document.getElementById('itemName').value;
    console.log(itemName);
    var url="searchItems.php";
    envelop = new XMLHttpRequest();
    envelop.open("POST",url,true);
    envelop.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    envelop.send('itemName='+itemName); 
    envelop.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (envelop.readyState === 4 && envelop.status === 200){
            displayResult(envelop.responseText)
        }
    };
    alert("Calling ajax");
}

function displayResult(response){
    document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML=responseText;
    alert("Part 2");
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code to ensure that the the function displayResult is being called :

`code`
function displayResult(){
 if((envelop.readyState==4) &&( envelop.status==200)){
  //document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML=envelop.responseText;
  document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML="Hello World";
  alert("Part 2");
 }
}
`code`

And I get the text "Hello World" in the div "desc"

Comment: do a console.log(envelop) inside the function and check the response in the console

Comment: did a console.log (envelop) and this is the result :

`code XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: displayResult(), readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "http://localhost/ebay/searchItems.p…", status: 200, statusText: "OK", responseType: "", response: "" } `

Comment: So the problem is not your ajax call, the response is empty, the problem should be on the php part getting the data

Comment: I cannot say that it is the php part, since when i press the submit button, I get the result on the page searchItems.php. can you please confirm ?

Comment: Yes it is! In your PHP you are checking for `isset($_POST["submit"])` that is true when you submit the form, but not in the ajax call, try with `isset($_POST["itemName"])` instead

Comment: I agree, I removed that `isset($_POST["submit"])` and its working now. Thanks very much

Answer (score -1):

use jquery ajax instead of javascript ajax.

like this

```
function ajax() {
var itemName = $('#itemName').val();
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: 'itemName='+itemName
       url: 'searchItems.php',
       success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
      });
 }
```